# PowerShell - How to execute script and save results in text file

Tags: powershell, scripting

I am very new to Powershell. I am trying to get a CPU maximum and average utilization while a particular process is running. I am using the below script but i am getting only the Average CPU Utilization at that moment.

```
Get-WmiObject win32_processor | Measure-Object -property LoadPercentage -Average | Select Average
```

Please help me with sample script for **"how can i get  CPU maximum and average utilization  for every 2 seconds for a particular process is running and store the result data in text file"**....

Comment: Are you wanting the average over a set ammount of time?

Comment: @Kevin_ Yes, Suppose i open `Command Prompt(cmd.exe)` and run some commands. During that time, i want to get the statistics of CPU utilization(max, avg) by the `cmd.exe` until `cmd.exe` is exited. I have Powershell already installed. Only i have to run the necessary scripts and save the results in text file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to sample every 2 seconds, and show max,min,ave for the whole period that cmd.exe is running then the code below will work. But if you want to sample the data every two seconds and show the max,min,ave for that 2 second interval then all 3 will be the same (because you only have 1 sample during that interval). You'll have to sample more frequently (like every .2 seconds) and then reset the $stats array after every two second interval. The code below isn't designed for that.

```
$cmdProcess = start-process cmd -passthru
$delay = 2
$stats = @()
$previous = ($cmdProcess|Get-Process).cpu
while (-not $cmdProcess.HasExited) {
  $latest = $cmdProcess|Get-Process
  $delta = $latest.cpu - $previous
  $delta
  $stats += $delta
  $previous = $latest.CPU
  sleep $delay
}
$stats|% {$_/$delay}|measure -max -min -ave
```

** updated 7/8 to fix bug - was collecting total time used by process (vs delta over 2 second interval) **

Comment: Am i getting Max, Min, Avg CPU utilization or Max%, Min%, Avg% of CPU Utilization?

Comment: Please see my question in `server fault` as well...http://serverfault.com/questions/521571/powershell-how-to-get-memory-max-avg-usage-page-fault-max-avg-usage-and

Comment: Script was collecting total time, and summing it together - which didn't make sense. Fixed to capture delta over 2 second interval. Now $stats is an array of amount of CPU seconds used for each interval. The final calculation divides by $delay to give total CPU seconds used in 1 sec wall clock time. So this is fraction of CPU time used on a SINGLE cpu. To get fraction of total, divide by # CPUs. For % mult by 100. *Note* that TASKMGR doesn't take into account that frequency of current CPUs can automatically be lowered, so taskmgr shows % of CPU at then current frequency.

Comment: How can i get Memory Usage, Page Fault and Network Usage for 3 `cmd.exe` processes? Please help me....

Comment: Can u please help me to get CPU, Memory Usage, Page Fault and Network Usage for 3 `cmd.exe` processes?

Comment: Please join in this chatroom to discuss: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33115/issue

Comment: Did this answer your original question?

Answer (score 0):

The reason that the Measure-Object command is giving you the same value for Max, Min, and Average, is because you are only passing it one single sample (i.e. the Max, Min and Average of one sample is always the same).

To get an average, you need to capture many samples (for ex. as long as the process "cmd" is running). I would store that information in an array, and then when I pass the array to my Measure-Object cmdlt, it will give me the correct Max, Min, Average.

**Edit Part 1: (rewritten to correct the code)**

Here is my code if you want to:

- Launch a cmd process
- Log the processing time into an array.

  - **Note:** Processing time is in seconds, and is cumulative (i.e. it keeps adding up)
  - We have to do some subtraction to get the "delta" or difference between the processing times. Also, sampling every second (rather than every 2 seconds) makes things easier for our calculations.
  - I multiply the delta by 10 to get a rough % CPU value
- Once the cmd process ends, it exits out of the while loop.
- Then, we use the Measure-Object to take the array, and calculate min, max, and avg values
- We then pipe the output to a text file (or the alternative would be to pipe the $array to the text file, where you could analyze the CPU over time).

.

```
$cmdProcess = start-process cmd -passthru

$array = @()
$LastCPU = $CmdProcess.CPU * 10

while(-not $cmdProcess.HasExited)
{
    $CurrentCPU = $CmdProcess.CPU*10
    $array += $CurrentCPU - $LastCPU
    $LastCPU = $CurrentCPU
    sleep 1
}

$array | Measure-Object -Average -Maximum -Minimum | Out-File c:\Output.txt
```

**EDIT Part 2:**

Your original Question was really two questions:

1. Why is the [below] script only returning Average CPU utilization? -- The answer to that is my explanation above.
2. How to get Min, max, avg CPU from a particular/multiple process (specifically multiple cmd.exe's)?

Based on your comments, I assume that part #2 is what you want... That takes a more time and explanation. I can give you a basic overview of what you will have to do.

If you used the above script, you control when you start the script and can get an accurate measurement of the CPU. If cmd.exe is already running, then you can't get accurate numbers (i.e. if the process has been running for 10 hours, you get the total seconds of CPU time that the process has used. You can't *easily* get min and max CPU from that, but using the StartTime property, you can get an average value).

I see two methods to get what you want:

1. "Wrap" whatever process you are launching with a PowerShell script. i.e. take the above script, and use it to launch the cmd processes. This way each PowerShell script controls a single cmd process which is being logging and measured, and will give you good numbers.
2. For processes that are currently running, you will have to use a script like this:

.

```
$cmdProcess = Get-Process cmd
$cmdProcess | foreach{
    $avg = $_.CPU / ([datetime]::Now - [datetime]$_.StartTime).TotalSeconds
    Write-Host "PID: $($_.Id)  CPU: $($_.CPU)  Average: $avg"
}
```

This is where you get all the "cmd" processes, loop through each process, calculate the average CPU utilization based on how long it has been running, and display the results (which could be sent to a file or wherever). You could then use this as part of another larger loop that runs and logs the cpu times for all the processes (similar to the first script). A complete larger final script would be beyond the scope of this question, and you will have to do some more research on your own to complete it, but this should give you a good start to things.

Comment: A couple of comments. `get-process cmd` will not detect termination of a particular cmd prompt if multiple cmd prompts are open. And win32_processor gives overall CPU utilization, not cmd's use of the CPU. Although from OP, it's not clear what was wanted.

Comment: @user2460798 yes, actually i will open multiple command prompts and have to get CPU Utilization of each command prompt separately and store the result in text file

Comment: @user2460798 In the same way, how can i get `Memory(GB)` max% and avg%, `Page Fault Rate` max%, avg% and `Network(Mbs)` max% and avg% for the 3 processes running.. Please help me.

Comment: Please see my question posted in `server fault` here: http://serverfault.com/questions/521571/powershell-how-to-get-memory-max-avg-usage-page-fault-max-avg-usage-and

Comment: @HAL9256 I am not getting text file to be stored with the code u have given

Comment: Please see above Edits to clarify the answer. To save the text file, you may have to run PowerShell as administrator for it save in certain locations (for ex. saving to C:\... on Win 7 you will need to run as administrator)